# Multiple Login endpoints in Jetty + Jersey

Tags: java, design-patterns, jersey, jax-rs, jetty

I'm building an application with an API layer. To access an API endpoint the request should carry a valid `token`. The token is generated and assigned upon successful authentication of a user. A user can be authenticated through multiple ways: `DB username/password check, FB, LDAP` and so on.

I currently have a `ServletContextHandler` executing a `Jersey Servlet Container`, serving endpoints `/api/*`.

Aim is to add login endpoints: `/login/fb, /login/myapp, login/ldap` 
 and I'm unsure where exactly it fits in. Should I add these as other endpoints in the jersey servlet or add a new custom servlet to handle these logins. Was wondering if there is another way of handling such multiple login endpoints in Jetty.

I do not use any xml to configure Jetty. The existing filters were configured through annotations and I would like to continue this way.

Haven't used Jetty before, not sure about the suitable architecture pattern applicable to this case.

Comment: you should add it a separate Servlet.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please explain why?

Comment: It provides Separation of concerns and adheres to Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: Okay, I get it. If I add this as an API endpoint, then the REST-API layer would also be responsible for generating these tokens. And thereby packing it with unnecessary responsibilities, while it should remain stateless. Makes sense.  Thanks